# Дискорд бот на питон отправляет вместо ссылок, рандомные буквы из ссылок

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py, photo

Решил сделать дискорд бота с помощью модуля Discord.py (модуль рандом тоже был использован)
Захотел чтобы бот выводил рандомные картинки, а он выводит рандомные буквы из данных ссылок (в перемменной meme)

````
async def meme(ctx):
    meme = [
        "https://imgur.com/t/pepe/qjxtX9W",
        "https://imgur.com/t/pepe/Wkrvc7Z",
        "https://imgur.com/gallery/s8iq8Qp",
        "https://imgur.com/gallery/4GUOjyS",
        "https://imgur.com/gallery/nkQ9Etq"
    ]
    rMeme = random.choice(meme)
    await ctx.send(random.choice(rMeme))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала берешь рандомную ссылку, а потом рандомный символ из ссылки. Попробуй так, без лишнего действия :)

```
async def meme(ctx):
    meme = [
        "https://imgur.com/t/pepe/qjxtX9W",
        "https://imgur.com/t/pepe/Wkrvc7Z",
        "https://imgur.com/gallery/s8iq8Qp",
        "https://imgur.com/gallery/4GUOjyS",
        "https://imgur.com/gallery/nkQ9Etq"
    ]
    rMeme = random.choice(meme)
    await ctx.send(rMeme)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь <3